# I have a jquery code to toggle a class that doesn't work and I can't figure out why

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to toggle prices in a form on and off with a checkbox using jQuery and CSS  classes but it does not work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ptgCheck").click(function() {
    $("#n1,#pp1,#pnp1 ").toggleClass("hide")
    $("#ptg1").toggleClass("show")

  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
#ptg1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <INPUT style="border:0;" id="ptgCheck" TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="product59[]" value="Yes">P Training Group

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="pp1">$100</div>
        <div id="n1">$310</div>
        <div id="pnp1">$260</div>
        <div id="ptg1">$400</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine ?

Comment: I pasted the code from your question in a stack snippet and it appears to work fine. Are you getting any errors in your browser's console in your code?

Comment: It's working for me by clicking "run code snippet". Which makes me think either your jQuery or stylesheet is not correctly loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't working due to the specificity of your CSS so it hides the elements but doesn't show the `#ptg1` the way you want. **Why?**

On CSS [the specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) defines which rule has more precedence over another, here your rule:

```
#ptg1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Has more precedence than

```
.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Therefore the element remains always hidden. The best solution is just set that class to the element on the beginning instead of create a CSS rule to hide it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ptgCheck").click(function() {
    $("#n1,#pp1,#pnp1,#ptg1").toggleClass("hide")
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <INPUT style="border:0;" id="ptgCheck" TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="product59[]" value="Yes">P Training Group
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="pp1">$100</div>
        <div id="n1">$310</div>
        <div id="pnp1">$260</div>
        <div id="ptg1" class="hide">$400</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I didn't know about the precedence rule. Thank you DaniP

Comment: Np mate glad to help U @Peter ; don't forget to mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you have too many classes for toggling. to be clear `hide` is the opposite of `show`, toggling the hide class doesn't need to set the show class and vise versa.

Just use one and set default states then toggle (on/off) the states.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ptgCheck").click(function() {
    $("#n1,#pp1,#pnp1,#ptg1").toggleClass("hidden")
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <INPUT style="border:0;" id="ptgCheck" TYPE="CHECKBOX" name="product59[]" value="Yes">P Training Group

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="pp1">$100</div>
        <div id="n1">$310</div>
        <div id="pnp1">$260</div>
        <div class="hidden" id="ptg1">$400</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: his `#pgt1` never shows when toggling the visibility of the divs I think that's what he means by not working.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Sorry I didn't explain it better. With the checkbox empty the table should show $100  $300  $260 and then when the checkbox is checked those should be hidden and $400 should be displayed. $400 should not be displayed initially.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS rule overrides all other rules because it selects by ID.

```
#ptg1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Remove it. And add initial **class="hide"** for **#ptg1** element.
Then you can use it as I showed in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjwpqvz4/1/).
I also would suggest using "display: none" instead of "visibility: hiddden", because the latter still takes place on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the suggestion. I will try it.

Comment: This worked great Vaidas, and it solved the problem of formatting where the $400 is below the other hidden values..Wahoo!